# MySql Query throwing an error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am just trying to use this as a very simple register system and i want to store the users and there passwords in my table users. Everything seems to work just fine up to the point were it actually executes the query. I believe it fails in a function called checkForDML(takes 2 parameters).  Please help thank you.

```
//password is just censored    
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gim?user=root&password=*********";
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String query = "Select * FROM users";

String user = txtUser.getText();
String password = txtPassword.getText();
txtUser.setText("");
txtPassword.setText("");
PreparedStatement ps;
query = "INSERT INTO gim.users(name, password) VALUES(?, ?)";
try
{
    Class.forName(dbClass).newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gim",   "root", "Pl4tf0rmD3v");
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, user);
    ps.setString(2, password);
    ps.executeQuery();
    conn.close();
}
catch(SQLException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2194)
at com.soe.sony.im.gui.GUI$2.actionPerformed(GUI.java:181)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It helps to see the exact error message.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the executeUpate() method rather than the executeQuery() method for an INSERT statement: [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

`ps.executeQuery();` should be `ps.executeUpdate();`

### ResultSet executeQuery()

Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and 
returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

### int executeUpdate()

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement 
object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE 
statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such 
as a DDL statement.

[Also have a look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756094/select-query-using-executeupdate-instead-of-executequery)

Good Luck!!!