# Behavior of SELECT query using executeUpdate

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have come across a strange behavior while executing a SELECT query using `Statement#executeUpdate()` by mistake. While the Javadoc clearly states that `executeUpdate() throws SQLException` if the given SQL statement produces a ResultSet object. But when I'm executing `SELECT * from TABLE_NAME`, I don't get any exception. Instead I'm getting an return value which is same as the no. of rows selected, if no. is less than or equal to 10. If the no. is more than 10, the return value is always 10.

```
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
try {
    conn = getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    int count = stmt.executeUpdate("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME");
    log.info("row count: " + count);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    log.error(e);
    // handle exception
} finally {
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(stmt);
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
}
```

I am using **Oracle 10g**.

Am I missing something here or is it up to the drivers to define their own behavior?

Comment: Be aware that the javadoc specifies the expected behavior, not necessarily the actual behavior as implemented in the specific driver!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is definetely contradicts `Statement.executeUpdate` API. What's interesting, 
`java.sql.Driver.jdbcCompliant` API says "A driver may only report true here if it passes the JDBC compliance tests". I tested `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.jdbcCompliant` - it returns true. I also tested `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.jdbcCompliant` - it returns false. But in the same situation as you describe it throws

`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue SELECT via executeUpdate().`

It seems that JDBC drivers are unpredictable.

Comment: What specifications state and what vendors deliver are still 2 different things it seems.

Comment: A comment in this related question explains the strange behavior for Oracle drivers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756094/select-query-using-executeupdate-instead-of-executequery

Answer (score 3):

According to the specifications `Statement.executeUpdate()` method returns `the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML)`.

**UPD**: I attempted to make an assumption about the returned result (which is always <=`10`). It seems, that the oracle statement's implementation returns here a number of a such called `premature batch count` (according to the decompiled sources `OraclePreparedStatement` class). This is somehow linked to the update statements. May be this value equals `10` by default.

**UPD-2:** According to this: [Performance Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97329_03/web.902/a90211/oraperf.htm): `The premature batch flush count is summed to the return value of the next executeUpdate() or sendBatch() method.`

Answer (score 2):

The query you are using doesn't produce a ResultSet but affects Rows obviously. That's why you don't get an SQLException but a count of the no of rows affected. The mystery is why it doesn't go beyond 10. May it is Oracle JDBC Driver Implementation Specific.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query is to retrieve all rows from table_name. So, you can use `execute()` method instead of `executeUpdate()` method. Because later method generally use when your task is related database manipulating language like update query.

Comment: Doesnt' answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

**use**

int count = **stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME")**;

**instead of**

int count = **stmt.executeUpdate("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME")**;

for **getting total no. of rows**.